# How do I resolve this error in the Raspberry Pi Kernel file bounds.c?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am new to kernel compilation. I want to create the Blinking LED driver for Raspberry Pi 1 Model B but as a first step towards the goal, I am trying to cross-compile unmodified Raspberry pi Kernel and following [this article.](https://kerneltweaks.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/led-blinking-driver-for-raspberry-pi/)

Everything goes fine until step 7. In step 7, when I enter cross compile command, it shows this:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}  
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bug.h:6:0,
                 from include/linux/bug.h:4,
                 from include/linux/page-flags.h:9,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:9:
./arch/arm/include/asm/opcodes.h:14:52: error: unknown type name 'u32'
./arch/arm/include/asm/opcodes.h:14:64: error: unknown type name 'u32'
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h:6:0,
                 from include/linux/irqflags.h:15,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:27,
                 from include/linux/bitops.h:36,
                 from include/linux/log2.h:16,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
./arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h:125:1: error: unknown type name 'bool'
./arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h: In function 'regs_get_register':
./arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h:141:6: error: expected expression before 'struct'
In file included from include/linux/bitops.h:36:0,
                 from include/linux/log2.h:16,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_set_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:38:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:38:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_clear_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:50:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_change_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:62:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_test_and_set_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:76:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_test_and_clear_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:93:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h: In function '____atomic_test_and_change_bit':
./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:110:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:122:0,
                 from include/linux/bitops.h:36,
                 from include/linux/log2.h:16,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__set_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:17:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__clear_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:25:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__change_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:42:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__test_and_set_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:59:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__test_and_clear_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:78:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function '__test_and_change_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:90:23: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h: In function 'test_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h:105:21: error: 'BITS_PER_LONG' undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:312:0,
                 from include/linux/bitops.h:36,
                 from include/linux/log2.h:16,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
include/asm-generic/bitops/fls64.h: At top level:
include/asm-generic/bitops/fls64.h:33:2: error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not 32 or 64
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:314:0,
                 from include/linux/bitops.h:36,
                 from include/linux/log2.h:16,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
include/asm-generic/bitops/sched.h: In function 'sched_find_first_bit':
include/asm-generic/bitops/sched.h:27:2: error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not defined
In file included from include/linux/log2.h:16:0,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:12:
include/linux/bitops.h: At top level:
include/linux/bitops.h:202:37: error: unknown type name 'u64'
include/linux/bitops.h:208:2: error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not 32 or 64
In file included from kernel/bounds.c:12:0:
include/linux/log2.h:32:17: error: unknown type name 'u32'
include/linux/log2.h:40:17: error: unknown type name 'u64'
include/linux/log2.h:52:1: error: unknown type name 'bool'
Kbuild:44: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:1004: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

I have not made any changes in any kernel file. I am not sure why bounds.c has a problem. Also, I downloaded the compressed version of the kernel file so I don't think it is a checkout/update issue. I have to confess I am confused as to what this error actually means. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
(1) `printenv` before step #6

```
$ printenv
XDG_VTNR=7
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/omkar
SESSION=ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/omkar/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
VTE_VERSION=4205
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
WINDOWID=58720266
KERNEL_SRC=/home/bhargav/rpi/linux-rpi-3.2.27
OLDPWD=/home/omkar/rpi
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1623
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module
USER=omkar
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/omkar/bin:/home/omkar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
PWD=/home/omkar/rpi/linux-rpi-4.4.y
JOB=unity-settings-daemon
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_US
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
HOME=/home/omkar
XDG_SEAT=seat0
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_US
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
LOGNAME=omkar
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-S9i5BrLSwB
CCPREFIX=/home/omkar/rpi/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
INSTANCE=
UPSTART_JOB=unity7
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/home/omkar/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

(2) Output of step #6

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} bcmrpi_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.hash.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

Comment: These errors are not a problem with bounds.c but likely with your environment setup, include path, etc.  You might want to check the output file to see how the tool chain resolved the macros to setup things like CCPREFIX.

Comment: (1) Edit your post to include the output of the `printenv` command before step #6. (2) Show the output of step #6.

Comment: Is your host machine is 32 bit where you cross compile the kernel?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer the host machine is 64 bit and I have libraries installed for cross-compiling on 64 bit machine

Comment: @Peter L Could you elaborate little more? I am totally new to this stuff..

Comment: @sawdust Just edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @EmbeddedManiac This is one of the most common issues when fresh building open source projects.  The first hint is `error: unknown type name 'u32'`.  The path to required headers is not resolved.  Those who put together this package probably included the necessary paths within a config file.  However, they are not being picked up in your build.  The good news is that once you fix the build environment things normally go smoothly -- you usually get no build errors vs. a gazillion.

Comment: @Peter L. Thanks.. Tried couple of things but no luck..

Comment: The problem is solved. I made a mistake in kernel version in the KERNEL_SRC path. Thanks to all of you for help. :)